# QWidget.update() or repaint() not refreshing the QWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create a GUI application in python using PyQt5 and wanted to implement splash screen in it. The problem is that after hiding the splash screen image I add a button to the same QWidget and call update() but it isn't showing.

### Code

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget,QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor,QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QTimer

class classer:
   def __init__(self):
      self.w=QWidget()
      self.w.setFixedSize(640,480)
      self.w.setWindowTitle("Classer")

   def splashScreen(self):
      img = QLabel(self.w)
      img.setGeometry(0,0,640,480)
      pixmap = QPixmap('SplashScreen.png')
      img.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(640,480,Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
      self.w.show()
      QTimer.singleShot(2000, img.hide)

   def mainScreen(self):
      btn=QPushButton(self.w)
      btn.setText('Click')
      btn.move(270,228)
      btn.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
      self.w.update()
      print("reached here!")

   def run(self):
      self.splashScreen()
      self.mainScreen()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication([])
   app.setStyleSheet(open('StyleSheet.css').read())
   instance=classer()
   instance.run()
```

### Splash Screen

[image]

### Current state after hiding image and calling .update()

[image]

### Desired state after hiding image and calling .update()

[image]

Comment: i think you just miss `btn.show()`  ?

Comment: Using btn.show() explicitly will paint the button at the start of the application itself over the splash screen. That is not desired.

Comment: then you can create a method to plug to the `singleShot` that will hide `img` and show `btn`. (may be handy to keep a reference to them --> `self.img` and `self.btn`)

Comment: or simpler : juste launch `self.mainScreen()` before `self.splashScreen()`

Answer (score 3):

The method `update` will only work on visible widgets ([doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update)), and the `QPushButton` is not visible since the `w.show()` method is called before the button creation. So you don't really need `update` here.

You can achieve this by moving some lines, like below :

```
   def splashScreen(self):
      img = QLabel(self.w)
      img.setGeometry(0,0,640,480)
      pixmap = QPixmap('background.png')
      img.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(640,480,Qt.KeepAspectRatio))    
      QTimer.singleShot(2000, img.hide)

   def mainScreen(self):
      btn=QPushButton(self.w)
      btn.setText('Click')
      btn.move(270,228)
      btn.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

   def run(self):    
      self.mainScreen()   # --> paint the button
      self.splashScreen() # --> paint the img on top layer
      self.w.show()       # --> display the widget
```

It's better to keep `self.w.show()` outside `splashScreen`, the whole widget will not depend on the splash display (in case you want to comment `self.splashScreen()` to save 2sec each time you run the program, for example).

Comment: Cool ! But why isn't .update( ) working in this case though?

Comment: `update` will only work on visible widgets ([doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update)), and the `QPushButton` is not visible since the `w.show()` method is called before the button is created

Comment: Didn't get it. What's the point of update( ) then if the widget must be created before? Can you give a minimal example?

Comment: An `update` or a `repaint` is used to trigger a refresh after some properties were changed, but it never touch hidden widgets. Check this [example](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Adding%20custom%20signals%20to%20a%20simple%20painted%20widget) of `update` case.